# Unable to open .xlsx file exported from Access 2010 using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010, export-to-excel

I'm having problems VBA code that exports a table from MS Access 2010 to an Excel 2010 format using the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` command. The code runs without error in Access and the file is created. However, when I try to open the file in Excel 2010 I receive the following error message:
    Excel cannot open the file 'XXXXX.xlsx' because the file format or file 
    extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and 
    that the file extension matches the format of the file.
Here is the code I use to setup for and then execute the export:

```
exportFileName = "\\network1\share$\filename_" & ".xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tablename", exportFileName, True
```

I looked at a number of possible solutions before posting, so I have tried

- replacing `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` with `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml`
- replacing `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` with the integer `10` or `9`
- ensuring that I had full access/permissions to the directory where I was saving the file
- opening the file from the `File -> Open` dialog rather than double-clicking the file
- saving the file to a local location, i.e. "C:\Users\paul\Documents\"

None of these solved the problem.

The one solution I found was as follows:

```
exportFileName = "\\network1\share$\filename_" & ".xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tablename", exportFileName, True
```

where the extension is `.xls` and the spreadsheet type is `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8`. I can work with this for now, but I would appreciate any other possible suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure table name is correct?...

Comment: Yes, the table name is correct - it's the same table name I use when I export to "xls" with a successful opening with Excel.

Comment: Try exporting table to spreadsheet on a local CPU disk and not network.

Comment: If you want to create an XLSX format workbook, use  [acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196017.aspx) instead of acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12.

Comment: @Parfait I had tried this but forgot to list it as one of my attempted solutions. Thanks for the reminder. @HansUp, I did mention trying out `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` in my note, but that did not fix anything.

Comment: It *is* the correct version constant, though. Try that again on a local disk.

Comment: @PaulCourtney After I do this in Access 2010 -> `exportFileName = "C:\Users\hans\Documents\filename_.xlsx"`, then `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tblFoo", exportFileName, True` and attempt to open the workbook file, I get the same Excel error message you reported.  But after deleting the file, and re-running the `TransferSpreadsheet` with `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` in place of `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12`, the workbook file can be opened successfully in Excel.  I can't understand why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @HansUp Well I did not delete the previous file when trying to use the method you mentioned. I assumed that the file would be overwritten. Apparently this is not really the case; I did as you mentioned and I deleted the previous `xlsx` file then re-ran the code using `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` and the file opened without error. So thank you! Please post your comment as an answer and I'll mark this question "Answered".

Answer (score 2):

I recently found another method that you can use to **export the excel file**.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "YourTableName", acFormatXLSX, exportFileName
```

This should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

exportFileName = "\network1\share$\filename";

This work well for me by without extend name,the system will determind for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).